# Custom Guard, get ID Route Params

Tags: angular

Wondering if we can get the :id of a route in the guard.

Example :

{path: ':id/admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard], data:{restricted: x}}

if User Reload I need to instantiate before some params to know if he is admin or not and de facto need the :id of this route URL
I would like also to come back to url/:id if he is not allowed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, first argument of canActivate is a snapshot of the route you're currently checking.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
   console.log(route.paramMap.get('id'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know why ActivatedRoute does not work outside of a component ? I was doing this in the service : this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('entityName'); Work everywhere but not here → return null

Comment: ActivatedRoute is tied tightly to a single route (ie. a component handling the route). Say you had a parent route with params and a child route with it's own params. In the child, paramMap only shows the child's own params, and in parent only it's own. Only "global" thing about a route is the url, that you can access anywhere from Router ie. this.router.url, but params only in route components.

Comment: thanks for your above comment I really do better understand now the use and difference of Activated Route.